# setInterval() is different between browser and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browser, timer

The global methods `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are different between browser (window) and NodeJS (global). The behavior is quite the same. Both doing the same.

See docs about [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) and [Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). In Node the returned value is a instance of a Timeout class. The browsers methods returns just a number, a handler id.

How to work with this difference if you developing for browsers but testing with Node, because test-framework engine is node (e.g. Jest). Do I need to switch to a browser test-engine?

(btw) Also, in my case I restrict all global variables. So I have to access only by the scope name. e.g. `window.setInterval` or `global.setInterval` not just `setInterval`. (It's a tslint rule `no-restricted-globals`)

Anyway there is a type conflict between Node's and browser's timer functions.
Is there a good practice to handle it? Do I have to switch my test-engine? But finally they doing the same. Maybe I have to cast to any-type?

I know this is not a JavaScript specification. It's the enviroment dependency. I do not say that they should be exactly the same. I'm just wondering how to deal with it when I run unit tests on node-js but I'm developing for browser. Currently only the return values are different. The behavior itself seems to be equal.

Comment: Why should it be exactly the same? `setInterval` is not a part of JS, its implementation is environment dependent.

Comment: Do you use the return type? If not, then you might be OK with just throwing away the signature. But in either case, you might try to semi-mock the timer functions - maybe create a fake `window` object and attack `setTimeout`/`setInterval` there and make them return a number (even if it's static) for test purposes.

Comment: you can use both `id` and `Timeout` class instance in `clearInterval` and in `clearTimeout`. So it shouldn't be any difference in tests

Comment: @Teemu I know. I did not say that they should be exactly the same. I'm just wondering how to deal with it when I run unit tests on node-js but I'm developing for browser.

Comment: Yes I use the return value to clearIntervals. Maybe a mock is a good idea.

Comment: Note about using both type: I set no-restricted-globals. This means I have to call `setInterval` over `window` or `global` like `window.setInterval`. Just `setInterval` is disallowed. So I have to mock window in node tests. ... 

Comment: @Dominik can you just do `window = { setTimeout: global.setTimeout }`?